# Seeking easy-Hebrew, high-interest books on Jewish topics for 8 year old boy

Tags: jewish-books, hebrew, children

Seeking titles of books and names of authors of high-interest children's books on Jewish topics in easy Hebrew with nikudot.  (Indications of reading grade level would be helpful.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84218/discussion-on-question-by-yehuda-w-seeking-easy-hebrew-high-interest-books-for).